# Update record field from Collection

Tags: record, elm

I am playing a little bit with Elm these days, but I stuck with a simple case where I want to update a record field. My code is like this:

```
-- MODEL


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { selectedLanguage = "german"
    , allCards = Card.cards
    }


type alias Msg =
    { description : String
    , data : String
    , id : String
    }
```

The update function

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case List.head (model.allCards) of
        Just card ->
            { card | fliped = True }
        Nothing -> model
```

but I see this:

```
Something is off with the 1st branch of this `case` expression:

50|             { card | fliped = True }
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The 1st branch is a record of type:

    { back : String, fliped : Bool, front : String, id : String }

But the type annotation on `update` says it should be:

    Model

Hint: Seems like a record field typo. Maybe back should be allCards?

Hint: Can more type annotations be added? Type annotations always help me give
more specific messages, and I think they could help a lot in this case!
Detected errors in 1 module.
```

I think I should always return a model from `update` function like my type says, but cannot figure out how. Any advice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have update the `allCards` field of `model` too. You can nest the card update inside the model update if the former returns a list instead of just a single card:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    { model
    | allCards =
        case model.allCards of
            card :: rest ->
                { card | fliped = True } :: rest

            [] ->
                []
    }
```

Or you can bind the new `allCards` to a name if you prefer:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    let
        newAllCards =
            case model.allCards of
                card :: rest ->
                    { card | fliped = True } :: rest

                [] ->
                    []
    in
    { model | allCards = newAllCards }
```

I pattern match directly on the list here instead of using `List.head`, as that also gives me the remainder of the list and I don't have to deal with an intermediary `Maybe` value (or two actually, since `List.tail` returns a `Maybe` as well). The `card::rest` branch hits if `allCards` contains at least one card, so the only remaining case is therefore `[]`, which is easy enough to handle.

Also, `flipped` is spelled with two `p`s ;)

Comment: Thanks @glennsl it makes sense. 

I can use this same approach if I want to not get the first element but someone based on an ID ?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use a pattern to find something by ID since that's not part of the "shape" of the data. Instead you could use `List.map` with a function that checks the ID and returns something else if it matches, and otherwise does nothing. E.g. `List.map (\item -> if item.id == 34 then { item | flipped = False } else item) items`

Comment: Or use `updateIf` from https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/6.1.0/List-Extra, that does exactly that